# How do I change my Office Communicator password?

Tags: passwords, microsoft-office-2007, office-communicator-2007

How do I change my Microsoft Office Communicator 2007 password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Office communicator is typically tied to Active Directory and is usually configured for single-signon.

[image]

What that means is that after you sign on to Windows, those credentials are sent in the background to the Communicator client as it starts up.

Changing your password on the domain depends on the domain policy, but generally it can be changed by pressing Ctrl-Alt-Del assuming you have a connection to a domain controller.

Answer (score 0):

Office Communicator uses the same password that you use to login to Windows (it's tied to your organization). I think the only way is to change your Windows password using 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Typically, Communicator 2007 is configured for you by your system administrator. It starts automatically when you log on to Windows using your "Windows logon password". Hence, when you change your Windows logon password, you have the Communicator password changed.